# Unknown character error in bison

Tags: c, parsing, ubuntu, bison, flex-lexer

I write a parser by bison , when I type this command in Ubuntu

```
 bison bison.txt
```

It returns these errors :

```
    Inspiron-N5110:~/Desktop/BisonProject$ bison bison.txt
    "bison.txt",  line 10: unknown character with code 0xd in declaration section
    "bison.txt", line 10: no input grammar
    *** Error in `bison': double free or corruption
    (!prev): 0x0000000000915780 *** Aborted (core dumped)
```

bison.txt :

```
%{ 
#include <ctype.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "lex.yy.c"
void yyerror(char *);
extern FILE* yyin;
extern char* yytext;
%} 

%token int_kw void_kw bool_kw open_bracket close_bracket number semicolon ID comma
%start Program

%%
Program:
    DeclarationList;

DeclarationList:
    DeclarationList Declaration | Declaration;

Declaration:
    VarDeclaration;

VarDeclaration:
    TypeSpecifier VarDecList;

VarDecList:
    VarDecList comma VarDecId | VarDecId;

VarDecId:
    ID | ID open_bracket number close_bracket  ;

TypeSpecifier:
    int_kw | void_kw | bool_kw;

%%

int main(){
  char fname[50];
  printf("Enter the name of your file:\n");
  scanf("%s",fname);

  fopen(fname,"r");

  yyparse();
  return 0;
}

void yyerror(char *s1){
  printf("%s\n",s1);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might want to use a different editor. One that does allow creating files with non M$-lineends. 0xd is CR which is added my notepad along with 0xa (LF) as line-end. Bison seems to expect LF lineends. You are feeding CRLF lineends.

Comment: Run `tr -d '\r' <bison.txt >bison.txt.nocrlf` and try to pass `bison.txt.nocrlf` to `bison`.

Comment: @alk I copy and past code to new empty Doc and my problem fixed ,

Comment: @alk but it return parser name defined to default :"parse"
and just make bison.tap.c and dose not make bison.tap.h

Comment: Run bison with the -d flag to get the .h file.

Comment: @alk   , my grammar file is grammar & and my parser file is bisonP . 
I enter these code in Ubuntu terminal:

lex grammar 
bison -d bisonP

and those worked but in genarated code is 
#include <conio.h>

conio.h is header of windows not ubuntu why this happen?
how solve this problem?

Comment: Have a look at the source you show and you feed to bison. `conio.h` (among other stuff) is in there explicitly!